# Dynamic casting from unsigned to signed in specman

Tags: specman

I'm trying to make casting in specman from unsigned to signed number using "as_a(int(bits:))".
My problem is that  is something that's dynamic and changes from one number to another.

When trying to pass a variable to  I'm getting an error saying that only constant numbers can be used.

Is there a way to overcome this? I've tried using macro but it didn't help as well.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's dynamic? Your original number is probably declared to be of a certain type (uint(bits: N) where N is hard-coded), isn't it? Maybe you can add an example to your question, so the problem will be clearer.

Comment: My problem is that the numbers coming from external input (file) and not declared inside e files, so their width can vary (and I know their width).
For example, I can have the following numbers:
0x5 --> should be translated to signed as 0x5.as_a(int(bits:3) --> -3;
0x82 --> should be translated to signed as 0x82.as_a(int(bits:8) --> -126

Comment: So, you actually get them as strings, not as numbers? You want to convert a *string* (such as `"0x5"` or `"0x82"`) to a correct numeric type?

Comment: I'm using eventually uint and not string because this is done at later stage after converting the strings to uints, but solution for strings can be good as well.

Comment: Still not sure what exactly your problem is. Once you already have a uint, why do you need to convert it to a shorter type, and what will this converted value be used for? Can you give some more specific example or fragment from your code?

Comment: The reason I need to convert it to shorter type is that I need its value in "signed" notation. As I wrote, if I have the number `0x5` in signed notation its value is different and equals to -3. This can be only achieved if I use the casting `as_a(int(bits:3))`.
To achieve similar behavior I've implemented the following:
`get_signed_value(unsigned_value: uint, bits_num:uint) : int is only {
        result = -(ipow(2,bits_num-1))* (unsigned_value[bits_num-1:bits_num-1]) + (unsigned_value[bits_num-1:0]];
 };`
Instead it could be great to use:
`result = unsigned_value.as_a(int(bits:bits_num));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function will convert the unsigned int(bits:*) to signed in a given amount of bits :

```
unsigned_to_signed(uval : int(bits:*), sz : uint, fix_range : bool = FALSE) : int(bits:*) is {
    assert(sz > 0) else error("unsigned_to_signed error: size must be possitive !");
    var max_val : int(bits:*) = 1.as_a(int(bits:*)) << sz;
    if (fix_range && uval >= max_val) { // fix uval to be in the range
        uval = (uval & (max_val -1));
    };
    assert (uval >= 0 && uval < max_val) else error(appendf("unsigned_to_signed error: uval is not in a valid range for int(bits:%u) !",sz));
    var sign_bit : int(bits:*) = 1.as_a(int(bits:*)) << (sz-1);
    if (uval < sign_bit) {
        return uval;
    } else {
        return -(max_val-uval);
    };
};
```

Usage Examples:

```
print unsigned_to_signed( (1).as_a(uint) , 8);
print unsigned_to_signed( (-1).as_a(uint(bits:8)) , 8);
print unsigned_to_signed( (127).as_a(uint) , 8);
print unsigned_to_signed( (-128).as_a(uint(bits:8)) , 8);
print unsigned_to_signed( (237).as_a(uint) , 9);
print unsigned_to_signed( (-237).as_a(uint(bits:9)) , 9);
print unsigned_to_signed( (-237).as_a(uint) , 9, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are trying to do: you have some number as uint and somehow know its "natural" bit size, and then you need to convert it to unsigned the way that leading 0s or 1s are correct according to that bit size. Right?

I don't see how it's possible to use variable bit size for integer. It seems that the only feasible solution, if you want to use the native 'e' casting, is to have all the possible bit size conversion hard-coded and use the relevant case according to bit size variable. It can be generated with relatively small amount of code using macros.

But maybe you don't really need as_a()? You can achieve correct sign extension using bit shift: convert your variable to int, and then shift it back and forth at distance 32 minus bit_size. At the end you should have the value you expect as an int: if it's positive for your bit size, it will be the same positive, and if it's supposed to be negative, it will be negative of correct value.

Comment: Thanks Rodion, both macro and shifting will solve the issue, but I think it's easier using the one line I've written in my solution.
Just wanted to know if there's no native "e" solution to this problem, it seems like it can be something useful to add.

Comment: There is a pretty good reason why in "int(bits:X)", X must be a constant: it defines type, and in 'e' types must be known at load/compile time. Dynamic operations with types in run time is possible using reflection, but for now there is no casting using reflection; it sounds like a very good idea to have it.